# SQL query to show Name and Department in a table

Tags: sql

Can you please help me, I don't know how to create this query. I am a front end dev.

Expected result should be table with 2 columns

Name(one) DepartmentName(many)

The tables and their relationship are shown in this image:

[image]

Comment: We should be able to ***help*** you if you describe what you already did and where exactly you're stuck. Please use [Edit] to add these details to your question.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Should the DepartmentName be a list or just multiple rows in the result table for each Department?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of `INNER JOINS`. You don't need to reference the `Location` table in this query because `Employee.LocationId` is the same as `EmployeeDepartment.LocationId`.

This simple query will return all employee names and all department names they are related to. The employee name may be repeated, as this query puts only one department name in the column, so if an employee is in two departments, you get the employee name twice.

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeName = e.Name
    ,DepartmentName = d.Name 
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN EmployeeDepartment ed ON ed.LocationId = e.LocationId
INNER JOIN Department d ON d.id = ed.DepartmentId
```

This query is a bit more complicated, but returns each employee name only once, and the department names will be a comma-separated string of names. This is accomplished by using `STUFF()` in conjunction with `FOR XML`.

```
;WITH EmployeesAndDepartments AS
(
    SELECT
        EmployeeName = e.Name
        ,DepartmentName = d.Name
    FROM Employee e
    INNER JOIN EmployeeDepartment ed ON ed.LocationId = e.LocationId
    INNER JOIN Department d ON d.id = ed.DepartmentId
)
SELECT
    ead.EmployeeName
    ,Departments = STUFF((
                             SELECT ',' + DepartmentName
                             FROM EmployeesAndDepartments
                             FOR XML PATH('')
                         ) , 1, 1, ''
                   )
FROM EmployeesAndDepartments ead
GROUP BY ead.EmployeeName
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT
      e.Name
    , d.Name AS DepartmentName

FROM
    Employee e

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    EmployeeDepartment ed
    ON e.LocationId = ed.LocationId

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Department d
    ON ed.DepartmentId = d.id
```

Note that the use of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`  will return the employee even if they don't have a corresponding record in EmployeeDeparatment and/or Department.  If you only want to retrieve employees that do have corresponding EmployeeDepartment and Department records, use `INNER JOIN` instead